# How to update table from independent to many to one relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables.
First:

```
---------------------
 ID  Statement 
---------------------
 1   First statement
 2   Another one
```

Second:

```
---------------------
 ID  Topic 
---------------------
 1   First topic
 2   Another topic
```

Until now statements were constant for all topics. For each topics all statements were shown.
Now I'd like statements to be dynamic and for each topic different, so I will need `Statement` table to look like:

```
-------------------------------
 ID  Statement          TopicID 
-------------------------------
 1   First statement     1
 2   Another one         1
 3   First statement     2
 4   Another one         2
```

How can achieve it?

**EDIT**

So far I was able to create table like this:

```
-------------------------------
 ID  Statement          TopicID 
-------------------------------
 3   First statement     1
 4   Another one         1
 5   First statement     2
 6   Another one         2
```

To do so I added new column to statements with `ALTER TABLE Statements ADD COLUMN TopicID int(10) UNSIGNED`.
So my table looked like this:

```
-------------------------------
 ID  Statement          TopicID 
-------------------------------
 1   First statement     0
 2   Another one         0
```

Next step was populating table with `INSERT INTO statements (Statement, TopicId) SELECT statements.Statement, topics.ID FROM statements, topics` query. This way `Statements` table was populated with `Statement`s and `TopicID` data:

```
-------------------------------
 ID  Statement          TopicID 
-------------------------------
 1   First statement     0
 2   Another one         0
 3   First statement     1
 4   Another one         1
 5   First statement     2
 6   Another one         2
```

The last step was to delete `statement`s with wrong `TopicID`s with `DELETE FROM Statements WHERE TopicID = 0`

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: why not create a new column in Statements and then update PK / FK with corresponding Topics?

Comment: That's what I want to do - create new column `TopicID`, with `ALTER TABLE Statements ADD COLUMN TopicID`. Now I stuck on populating rest of data - for each topic I need to make a copy of all statements, so editing one statement for one topic will not have an influence for the other.

Comment: You can use `UPDATE` + `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Finnally I've used `INSERT INTO statements (Statement, TopicId)
SELECT statements.Statement, topics.ID 
FROM statements, topics` Now I've got additonal rows with TopicId equal 0. I don't know how to use `UPDATE` + `LEFT JOIN` for it.

Comment: Solved by using `UPDATE` + `LEFT JOIN` - should I post it as an answer to your question?

Comment: If you will post your solution with `UPDATE` + `LEFT JOIN` I will be grateful.